How can I add the "Open in xxx" context menu in WKWebView, similar to SFSafariViewController?
When I long-press a Universal Link on a website loaded in SFSafariViewController, I see a context menu action called Open in "{App}"
Does anyone know how to enable that menu action when the website is loaded in WKWebView?
Note: I also observed that this context menu is only available in Apple's apps like Notes and Safari. Not sure if they’re using any private APIs or methods in Swift/Objective-C.

